# Rows being repeated in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I know this question has appeared a number of times but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work.
The fact that getView is called multiple times in certain cases.

However, in the example given here: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296
it says that the first call for each row in the data should get a null value in currentView.
This is not happening.

What is happening for me is that the calls when position is 0 has currentView set to null whereas the calls where position is 1 has currentView set to an existing object.

In total 16 calls are made to "getView" but I get the rows duplicated once (i.e two of each row).
Row 0
Row 1
Row 0 
Row 1

I probably just didn't understand something from that post.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_paired_devices" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#666"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_other_devices"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#666"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/new_devices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_scan" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_scan"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Listview row:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.

android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Device Address -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvwDeviceAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Display Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvwDisplayName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvwDeviceAddress"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
    private class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<MPGDeviceDetails> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<MPGDeviceDetails> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        Log.e("MPG","Position = " + position + ".  ConvertView = " + convertView);
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_name, null);

        TextView address = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvwDeviceAddress); // Device Address
        TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvwDisplayName); // Display name
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image



        address.setText(data.get(position).deviceAddress);
        name.setText(data.get(position).getDisplayName());
        Bitmap photo = data.get(position).getContactPhoto();
        if (photo != null)
            thumb_image.setImageBitmap(photo);


        return vi;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Setup the window
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.device_list);

    // Set result CANCELED incase the user backs out
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

    // Initialize the button to perform device discovery
    Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doDiscovery();
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and
    // one for newly discovered devices


    // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
    pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    pairedDevicesList = new ArrayList<MPGDeviceDetails>();
    pairedListView.setAdapter((mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new LazyAdapter(this,pairedDevicesList)));
    pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
    registerForContextMenu(pairedListView);

    // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
    mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // Get a set of currently paired devices
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
          pairedDevicesList.add(MPGDeviceDetailsControl.getDeviceDetails(this, device.getAddress(), device.getName()));
        }
    } 

}
```

MPGDeviceDetails is an object that holds all the data about a specific device.

This is the output from the "debug" command:

```
03-27 10:03:30.730: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = null.
03-27 10:03:30.742: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@4062d608. 
03-27 10:03:30.746: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = null. 
03-27 10:03:30.750: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@40628d78. 
03-27 10:03:30.750: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@4062d608. 
03-27 10:03:30.753: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@4062d608. 
03-27 10:03:30.753: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@40628d78. 
03-27 10:03:30.753: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@40628d78. 
03-27 10:03:30.761: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@4062d608. 
03-27 10:03:30.761: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = null. 
03-27 10:03:30.769: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@40628d78. 
03-27 10:03:30.769: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = null. 
03-27 10:03:30.777: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = null. 
03-27 10:03:30.781: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@406d4af8. 
03-27 10:03:30.781: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = null. 
03-27 10:03:30.785: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@40694970. 
03-27 10:03:30.789: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@406d4af8. 
03-27 10:03:30.789: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@406d4af8. 
03-27 10:03:30.789: E/MPG(2841): Position = 0.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@40694970. 
03-27 10:03:30.792: E/MPG(2841): Position = 1.  ConvertView = android.widget.RelativeLayout@40694970.
```

This is what the screen looks like:
[image]

Funny thing is that, whilst all 4 buttons work, the context-menu only works for the first two!

Comment: why don't you post some code so we can figure out what is going wrong

Comment: `the first call for each row in the data should get a null value in currentView.` This is incorrect. Android may use a previously use view for any row past the first one, and often does. Simply reuse the given view by changing its content.

Comment: Added thr code. Hopefully someone can help me please. Need to show it to a potential employer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter when you've finished filling `pairedDevicesList`:

```
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        pairedDevicesList.add(MPGDeviceDetailsControl.getDeviceDetails(this, device.getAddress(), device.getName()));
    }
}
((BaseAdapder)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or create adapter after filling `pairedDevicesList`.

Also try stating that your adapter's data has stable ids:

```
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, you show `<ListView android:id="@+id/new_devices" .../>` somehow. Try removing it from your layout for a while.

Comment: Perfect! Doing that pointed me to the mistake: newDevicesListView.setAdapter(new LazyAdapter(this,pairedDevicesList));  Connected the wrong list to the View.

Comment: So what you connected to the list now.. Have you replaced newDevicesListView.setAdapter(new LazyAdapter(this,pairedDevicesList));

Answer (score 0):

In general, besides regular getView calls for each item(s), it is called about 3 times more because it needs to calculate measurements for the views for scrollbar size, layout, etc. Regarding the duplicate rows, i think you should paste your code. You might be doing something else wrong.

For more info, view [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196219/android-adapter-multiple-getview)

Answer (score 0):

The `currentView` value should be used to optimization issues. Android propose to reuse views to save the memory and more quicker response.

When yor `currentView` isn't null then you can use it to display current item.
Take a look at example:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        // we can't reuse view and must read it from layout
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.whatever, null);
    }

   // ... use v as view for row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `clear` the ArrayList before adding values to it.

here in your `if` condition

```
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) { 
 pairedDevicesList.clear();
 // other code as it is
}
```

also you can put one log before you clear the ArrayList.

```
Log.i("Size","ArrayList Size = "+pairedDevicesList.size());
```

So you will get more idea.

Comment: Still no good. Shows it as empty before I fill it and then having 2 rows after I fill.